# How we could emulate Android apps installations so Google would count it as actual legit installation?

Tags: java, android, download, google-play, apk

what we want is to figure out the way how we could emulate installations so Google would count it as actual legit installation,let's say we have valid gmail account,login/password etc. everything including proxy address.there is even a real human/user used that account for some time. the question is how could we simulation certain application installation for that gmail user

Comment: And you want to do this for a purpose other than falsifying the install count for your application?